# Google App Engine writing Permission denied

Tags: php, google-app-engine, laravel-5, file-permissions, octobercms

I have uploaded my OctoberCMS (Laravel 5 based CMS) to Flexible Google App Engine using  following console command:

```
╭─yusuf@berkarya ~/htdocs/Project_October 
╰─➤  gcloud app deploy
```

And then it deployed to the Cloud Service with following messages:

```
Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...done.                                                                                                      
Setting traffic split for service [default]...done.                                                                                                                     
Stopping version [obundaoctober/default/20180614t144216].
Sent request to stop version [obundaoctober/default/20180614t144216]. This operation may take some time to complete. If you would like to verify that it succeeded, run:
  $ gcloud app versions describe -s default 20180614t144216
until it shows that the version has stopped.
Deployed service [default] to [https://obundaoctober.appspot.com]

You can stream logs from the command line by running:
  $ gcloud app logs tail -s default

To view your application in the web browser run:
  $ gcloud app browse
```

The problem is when I tried open following url https://obundaoctober.appspot.com I got an error message that inform me it has no sufficient permission access:

```
We're sorry, but an unhandled error occurred. Please see the details below.

The stream or file "/app/storage/logs/system.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied
/app/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php line 107
```

[image]

Any proper way to change folder/file permission in flexible Google App Engine to solve this kind of error ?

Any help will be extremely appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Could you ssh into your App Engine Flex instance and try changing the permission manually? This looks like it's trying to write into `root` directory, but below you tried to overwrite 'storage\/' which will be somewhere inside `home` directory.

Comment: app engine is not something like virtual machine or Compute engine, 
in app engine the deployed app runs live code. It is not generally feasible to edit it. Moreover, changes made to the running container are not permanent; in fact they and are lost at the first re-start.  actually I've moved to the Compute engine to avoid this issue

Comment: As I understood you are running flexible in which case it's possible: go to App Engine dashboard, there select a flex service and then click on the number of instances. As long as there are more then 0 instances you should be able to pick one and ssh into it right there.

Comment: yeah, I know, if so then whenever I re-deploy the app  I have to keep doing same thing to fix this issue, app engine is based on docker, every time I deploy the container will be destroyed recreated, I think move to compute engine is the only solution here

Comment: To be more precise: could you check where file of interest really is? Because if you are giving permissions for `storage\/` in `composer.json` you are probably editing your "`home`" , i.e. `/home/vmagent/app/storage` but the file that gives you errors is in `root`, i.e "`/app/storage/logs/system.log`". So it could be that you should edit "`/app/storage`" and not just  "`storage/`". Once you established where the file is you can reflect it in `composer.json`.

Comment: pardon, @A.Queue, but have you deploy Framework/CMS to App Engine Before ?

Comment: I haven't deployed any Framework/CMS in php GAE. Considering that the application gives an error and the obvios solution presented before hadn't bear any fruit is it inappropriate to begin the troubleshooting from the running environment?

Comment: yeah I can fix it directly on instance, but GAE is container based Cloud Platform (it's quite different with Compute engine/VPS) it will destroyed and re-created everytime I deploy the project from my local again and again ( $ gcloud app deploy), You are right about the permission issue... but I need particular solution for  Google app engine it will be something in app ngine configuration file app.yaml

Comment: similar with docker instance, if you got something wrong in instance you need to fix something in your Dockerfile / docker-compose.yml file not to fix it directly in your instance

Answer (score 0):

In the [GAE tutorial for Laravel](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-flexible) is an example to change permissions in the post-install-cmd in composer.json

```
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "chmod -R 755 bootstrap\/cache",
        "php artisan cache:clear"
    ]
}
```

I think this will also work with the storage folder.

Comment: in OctoberCMS bootstrap\/cache is note available, actually I've tried that and gave me another deployment issue and error... actually that was my first error before got this permission error...

Comment: You would have to change 'bootstrap\/cache' to 'storage\/'

Comment: hmhmh.... I think the only solution is using real Compute Engine, the App engine is extremely limited in feature and capability, it's only sufficient to host static html only I guess

Answer (score 0):

You can set "runtime: custom" in app.yaml and configure the Docker container with a Dockerfile. In the Dockerfile you can set the write permissions.

```
FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/php73
 
ARG COMPOSER_FLAGS='--prefer-dist'
ENV COMPOSER_FLAGS=${COMPOSER_FLAGS}
ENV SWOOLE_VERSION=4.3.4
ENV DOCUMENT_ROOT=/app
 
COPY . $APP_DIR
 
RUN apt-get update -y \
&& apt-get install -y \
unzip \
autoconf \
build-essential \
libmpdec-dev \
libpq-dev \
&& pecl install decimal \
&& curl -o /tmp/swoole.tar.gz https://github.com/swoole/swoole-src/archive/v$SWOOLE_VERSION.tar.gz -L \
&& tar zxvf /tmp/swoole.tar.gz \
&& cd swoole-src* \
&& phpize \
&& ./configure \
--enable-async-redis \
&& make \
&& make install \
&& chown -R www-data.www-data $APP_DIR \
&& /build-scripts/composer.sh \
&& mv $APP_DIR/storage $APP_DIR/storagestatic \
&& ln -s /tmp $APP_DIR/storage \
&& cp -TRv $APP_DIR/storagestatic/ $APP_DIR/storage/ \
&& chown -R www-data.www-data $APP_DIR/storage \
&& chmod -R 777 $APP_DIR/storage ;
 
ENTRYPOINT ["/build-scripts/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf"]
 
EXPOSE 8080
```

Full tutorial: https://webmotion.medium.com/how-to-install-octobercms-laravel-application-on-google-app-engine-c77a9185f420